# What ($\le $) 500-digit number has 62,118 steps ? (Collatz conjecture)

Tags: collatz-conjecture

According to this site : https://www.nitrxgen.net/collatz
[update 8'2023: the site seems to be down. An archived version of the site can be found at webarchive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160319021630/https://www.nitrxgen.net/collatz ]

The maximum steps registered so far for a given number (with less than 500 digits) is **62,118**, do we know what number it is?

I tried to contact the admin to give this result but I haven't got any response yet, maybe this is a known number in the community?

Thanks

> The greatest number of steps I've seen from a single submitted number so far is 62,118 (abiding by the 500 digit restriction) and was found on 18/01/2015.

**Update - I got an answer from the admin :**

> The number that generated 62,118 steps is a 500 digit number, the form
> limit. The highest value of any step occurs at step 132.
>
> This number was found by an unknown user in January 2015, the same
> month the tool was released which is kind of weird (this number was
> the 47th ever number to be submitted), there has been no other number
> submitted that has beaten that record of steps and there's been 2.6
> million submissions at the time of me writing this email.
>
> The number is seeminly random with no obvious pattern:
>
> 81710902424862408424 <460 digits omitted> 82927666062150148665.
>
> If you would still like the number then let me know but all I ask is
> that you don't submit it unnecessarily to my site. Thanks for your
> understanding!

Comment: Since we know so few generalities about the Collatz map, my immediate guess would be that if anyone knows that there is a number which takes 62,118 steps to get to 1, then that's because they have found such a number explicitly and checked.

Comment: @Arthur yes, that's what I'm trying to find out, if anyone knows the value of this number ?

Comment: I ran a random search overnight in the range $10^{500}-1\geq x\leq 10^{499}-1$ testing numbers with a density of one in $2^{1599}$ in the odd integers and the longest sequence found was that of $10^{500}-1$ with $16336$ steps. What this underlines is that the outliers are relatively sporadic. A better strategy may be to select numbers high in the range whose modular properties guarantee that they will initially climb significantly. I certainly tested the same number many times and there will be more efficient methods

Answer (score 6):

This is not the answer, but an attempt to find it.

It is easy to find a number that takes $k$ Collatz steps to reach $1$, namely $2^k$. This is of course gets infeasibly large, and exceeds the 500 digit limit of that site when $k>1661$.

You can of course do better by not just inverting the 'divide by $2$' step $k$ times to get a number that needs $k$ steps, but also but using an inverse $3x+1$ step when it is possible and useful, because that keeps the number small.

I tried doing this in a slightly naive way, by repeating:

If $x \equiv 4\ or\ 16 \mod 18$ then do $x\to (x-1)/3$ else do $x\to 2x$.

I started at $x=8$ so that it wasn't stuck in the $1,2,4$ loop from the start.

BTW, the reason for the mod is that the $3x+1$ rule with $x$ odd always results in a number that is $4 \mod 6$ so the inverse of that rule is only allowed if we have such a number. We also want to avoid getting an $x$ that is a multiple of $3$ (which happens when the input $x$ is $1 \mod 9$) because otherwise all further inverted steps will be doublings.

The best result for a number that still lies within the 500 digit limit was one that takes $7449$ steps.

Clearly the person who found a number within that limit that takes so many more steps must have been doing something much more clever.

FYI, the $7449$-step number I found is:

$99128,42552,45070,58214,49794,21433,09617,71434,\\
35751,13169,69228,12299,48208,17398,14999,66674,\\
07909,73211,57857,75169,98703,66806,51365,17271,\\
44964,80888,82391,81744,25916,60261,13042,03866,\\
66103,49056,80916,51374,86393,63112,68646,00014,\\
51265,78980,63819,41418,78232,36960,28854,91873,\\
32045,03658,35551,66924,74284,74756,27331,65465,\\
06917,90508,40100,42755,07304,51692,27781,51879,\\
28347,37220,21499,69801,81717,10793,96853,00241,\\
92286,70480,20097,55644,06511,04039,72081,20501,\\
67137,12978,12761,35222,27067,25690,90233,93366,\\
78269,76657,53601,98939,20113,98389,35981,59681,\\
41626,53623,05243,67777$

**Edit:**

A different but equally naive method is to just try various random numbers, but preferably those whose binary expansion ends in lots of ones because those will cause the $3x+1$ rule to be chosen many times at the start of the Collatz sequence, making for a bigger number.

The best 500-digit number I found used $25858$ steps, and is:
$16910 \cdot 2^{1646} - 1=$

$52907,40618,32017,54152,63867,78240,01344,94071,\\
10672,87955,14970,95443,32426,37432,94723,15343,\\
69589,15667,94197,77289,84251,30595,66986,13736,\\
01999,30240,57853,88392,15872,66353,93648,16021,\\
76528,02318,47325,39772,11544,04475,63943,10264,\\
65156,58431,35122,30262,85026,21429,61128,92928,\\
64147,40168,11368,14718,14844,43105,54823,58463,\\
32284,16963,01649,12670,32815,41060,21677,81365,\\
13557,54204,91127,46553,29004,21933,21888,08910,\\
76179,94524,51718,32033,27205,55270,66366,57606,\\
00582,53081,68267,14042,35673,44288,21454,35891,\\
44482,68697,66804,20865,40074,26362,70517,10800,\\
03191,26585,23809,38239$

Comment: Just by inputting random 500 digits numbers, it's easy to find steps around 10k/15k (max I've done is 16k), which is far lower from 62k...

Comment: I'm not sure how many steps it will take, but the 500 digit number that will take the most steps, should be the number with 1660 binary 1 digits.